# How can I get form value and push it to array ? (fixing code)

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to code my first hangman.

I need to take the value from the html input and store it into an array.

I tried to store the value using a submit button, called "Guess".

```html
<form>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" minlength="1" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Guess a letter" />

<button class="guess" name="guess" type="button" value="Guess">Guess</button>

<button id="restart" name="restart" type="button">Restart</button>
</form>
```

```
const guessButton = document.querySelector(".guess");


//empty array to store letters
guesses = [];
//store letter in array 

guessButton.addEventListener("submit", e=> {
    e.preventDefault();

    const letter = document.querySelector("#letter").value;
    //store letter in array 
    guesses.push(letter);
    console.log(guesses);
});
```

There is no result, it seems I cannot obtain the value.

Thank you for the support!

Comment: GuessButton will not fire an event `submit`, `submit` will work on form elements though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `click` instead of `submit`

```js
var guessButton = document.querySelector("#guess");


//empty array to store letters
var guesses = [];
//store letter in array 

guessButton.addEventListener("click", e=> {
    e.preventDefault();

    var letter = document.querySelector("#letter").value;
    //store letter in array 
    guesses.push(letter);
    console.log(guesses);
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Ex</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" maxlength="1" minlength="1" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Guess a letter" />
            
            <button class="guess" id="guess" name="guess" type="button" value="Guess">Guess</button>
            
            <button id="restart" name="restart" type="button">Restart</button>
            </form>  
                
    </body>
</html>
```